# Kotlin. Возобновление таймера в функции CountDownTimer

Tags: android, kotlin

Таймер

```
 var milliseconds: Long = 180000      

 var timer = object :   CountDownTimer(milliseconds, 1000) {     
     override fun onTick(seconds: Long) {
         milliseconds = seconds / 1000
         textView4.text = String.format("%02d:%02d", seconds / 60000, seconds % 60000 / 1000)
     }
```

После остановки таймера через команду

```
timer.cancel()
```

И после возобновления через команду `timer.start()`
Таймер сбрасывается и начинает идти заново, как можно сделать так, чтобы после остановки таймера и возобновления он продолжал идти с места остановки, мне казалось, что 1 переменная milliseconds изменяясь после каждого тика, будет сохранять результат, но она всегда статична

Comment: можно задать переменную которая будет последним значением таймера

Comment: Создавал отдельную переменную, также после тика присваивал значение milliseconds и в функции старта присваивал значение таймеру, но безуспешно

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ты должен снова инициализировать объект timer, чтобы он возобновил работу с того момента.
Если снова не инициализировать , то milliseconds не будет меняться и будет 180к.

Если хочешь возобновить:

```
    var timer = object : CountDownTimer(milliseconds, 1000) {
      ...
     }
```

Comment: как сделать так что бы timer считал с нуля?

Comment: override fun onTick(millisUntilFinished: Long) {
180000 - (millisUntilFinished/1000);
}